# Qt: Creating a QDoubleSlider

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, signals-slots, qslider

I want to connect a `QDoubleSpinBox` with a `QSlider` like this:

```
QObject::connect(ui->myDoubleSpinBox, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), 
ui->mySlider, SLOT(setValue(double)));
    QObject::connect(ui->mySlider, SIGNAL(valueChanged(double)), 
ui->myDoubleSpinBox, SLOT(setValue(double)));
```

This won't work, for a QSlider only handles int values. So I think i need to add a custom slot to QSlider.
I thought about creating a new class derived from QSlider and then implementing the slot, like this:
QDoubleSlider.hpp

```
#ifndef QDOUBLESLIDER_H
#define QDOUBLESLIDER_H

#include <QSlider>

class QDoubleSlider : public QSlider
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit QDoubleSlider(QObject *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
    void setValue(double givenValue);
};

#endif // QDOUBLESLIDER_H
```

QDoubleSlider.cpp

```
#include "qdoubleslider.h"

QDoubleSlider::QDoubleSlider(QObject *parent) :
    QSlider(parent)
{
}

void QDoubleSlider::setValue(double givenValue)
{
    // code
}
```

Now I have two problems:

1. The compiler complains about an invalid conversion from `QObject*` to `QWidget*` in the constructor.
2. I don't know how setValue works and thus I don't even know how to implement that slot.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

1. `parent` needs to be a `QWidget*`, just as the error states
2. Slots work like regular member functions. You should probably store an exact `double` as a member and set the underlying slider to the appropriate integer equivalent. Remember to only send `valueChanged` signals if the value really changes.

Furthermore you should probably inherit from `QWidget` instead and have a `QSlider` as a child, as you do not want users of your class to change the integer range of your internal slider.

Answer (score 1):

1. just simply replace your QObject to QWidget, because QSlider constructor is

   `QSlider ( QWidget * parent = 0 )`
2. you'd better have a new slot named setDoubleValue(double givenValue) and connect to this slot. in this slot, it is simple. like

   `void QDoubleSlider::setDoubleValue(double givenValue)
   {
       setValue(static_cast<int>(givenValue));
   }`